# Framework not found error after adding my own framework

Tags: xcode, macos, frameworks

I'm trying to learn a framework flow using this guide: https://www.raywenderlich.com/126365/ios-frameworks-tutorial. Created a separate cocoa framework project, moved some code there - it builds successfully, resulting in *DehancerNavigation.framework* file.

Now I'm trying to add this framework to another project: just created a blank project for this and added my framework to *Embedded binaries* in on *General* tab. It also appeared in *Linked Frameworks and Libraries* section.

[General tab with added framework](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hdRZ3.png)

Seems to be enough, but now I get a buildtime error:

> Ld    /Users/yefim/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DehancerNavigationTestUsageProject-eqegtcmqsajracgiyxgidupllvbp/Build/Products/Debug/DehancerNavigationTestUsageProject.app/Contents/MacOS/DehancerNavigationTestUsageProject normal x86_64
>
> cd /Users/yefim/Documents/Projects/DehancerNavigationTestUsageProject
>
> export MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.13
>
> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk -L/Users/yefim/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DehancerNavigationTestUsageProject-eqegtcmqsajracgiyxgidupllvbp/Build/Products/Debug -F/Users/yefim/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DehancerNavigationTestUsageProject-eqegtcmqsajracgiyxgidupllvbp/Build/Products/Debug -filelist /Users/yefim/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DehancerNavigationTestUsageProject-eqegtcmqsajracgiyxgidupllvbp/Build/Intermediates.noindex/DehancerNavigationTestUsageProject.build/Debug/DehancerNavigationTestUsageProject.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/DehancerNavigationTestUsageProject.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/../Frameworks -mmacosx-version-min=10.13 -Xlinker -object_path_lto -Xlinker /Users/yefim/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DehancerNavigationTestUsageProject-eqegtcmqsajracgiyxgidupllvbp/Build/Intermediates.noindex/DehancerNavigationTestUsageProject.build/Debug/DehancerNavigationTestUsageProject.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/DehancerNavigationTestUsageProject_lto.o -Xlinker -export_dynamic -Xlinker -no_deduplicate -fobjc-link-runtime -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/macosx -Xlinker -add_ast_path -Xlinker /Users/yefim/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DehancerNavigationTestUsageProject-eqegtcmqsajracgiyxgidupllvbp/Build/Intermediates.noindex/DehancerNavigationTestUsageProject.build/Debug/DehancerNavigationTestUsageProject.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/DehancerNavigationTestUsageProject.swiftmodule -framework DehancerNavigation -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/yefim/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DehancerNavigationTestUsageProject-eqegtcmqsajracgiyxgidupllvbp/Build/Intermediates.noindex/DehancerNavigationTestUsageProject.build/Debug/DehancerNavigationTestUsageProject.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/DehancerNavigationTestUsageProject_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/yefim/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DehancerNavigationTestUsageProject-eqegtcmqsajracgiyxgidupllvbp/Build/Products/Debug/DehancerNavigationTestUsageProject.app/Contents/MacOS/DehancerNavigationTestUsageProject
>
> ld: framework not found DehancerNavigation
>
> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation).

Is there something else I need to setup to use framework in project?

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved when I copied framework to my project folder instead of making a reference to it (*copy items if needed* checker should be set).